# PHP Header Content-Disposition: attachment forces .php file or inline

Tags: php, header, download, cross-browser, mp3

I want to download a single .mp3 file from my site but when using this code it forces a .php in Firefox and Safari. But in chrome it will send force the file as inline and play on the page. How can i get them to actually download a .mp3 file?

```
$track = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

if (file_exists("/home/user/gets/" .$track)) {
    header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($track));
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.mp3"');
    $str = "/home/user/gets/".$track;
    readfile($str); 
    exit;
} else {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found', true, 404);
    echo "no file";
}
```

I have also tried to download a .zip file as well and changing the Content-Type to application/ocetet-stream but it forces .php files on all browsers.

```
//$track = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$track = 'testfile.zip';
if (file_exists("/home/user/gets/" .$track)) {
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($track));
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.mp3"');
    $str = "/home/user/gets/".$track;
    readfile($str); 
    exit;
} else {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found', true, 404);
    echo "no file";
}
```

Comment: I think `filesize($track)` is wrong, it should be the whole path `filesize("/home/user/gets/".$track)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `filesize($track)` is wrong, it should be the whole path `filesize("/home/user/gets/".$track)`. This would cause php to output error messages, preventing you from setting the content-length and disposition header.

Comment: Yep, this was the main problem along with MarcB. Both of you were correct. Thank you

Answer (score 9):

Try taking the quotes off the filename:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.mp3');
                                                  ^^^^^
```

Getting the name of the script instead of the filename you're trying to use is generally a sign that the filename contains invalid characters for the filesystem the browser's trying to save to. e.g. `"` isn't permitted.

Comment: This was also apart of the problem. Thank you